# What happens if my bean is declared @ApplicationScoped , but it has a public field?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

According to the javadocs(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/package-summary.html) if a bean has a public field it should be classified as @Dependant.

In our code base we have a situation where a bean is both @ApplicationScoped and @Singleton , but it has public fields. Will this bean be treated as @Dependant or will it still work as @ApplicationScoped since no errors are thrown?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your container is not fully complying with the J2EE specification, this is an invalid bean and the container should prevent the application from starting.  I've confirmed this is the case with Tomee 1.7.2.

Public fields are not allowed on managed beans because the container isn't able to proxy them.  This is essential when it comes to injecting lower scopes into higher ones (`@Request` into `@Application` for example).  I suspect your container is allowing this since it doesn't need to proxy `@ApplicationScoped` beans.

That being said, I'd suggest you just change your code to make it compliant with the specification, even if your container is not, otherwise it's likely to break after a future upgrade/migration!

Comment: We use weblogic as our container. It would be great if it actually failed instead of running with you having no clue as to how it is handling the error.